# Unspecified I/O Standard: 5 out of 5 logical ports use I/O standard

Tags: vhdl

I keep getting this error when I generate the bitstream in my VHDL code. I'm not sure why its not working, I believe it has something to do with either the constraint file or lower module. My code is similar to my classmates but I'm the only one running into this issue.

here is the full Error message

> [DRC NSTD-1] Unspecified I/O Standard: 4 out of 4 logical ports use I/O standard (IOSTANDARD) value 'DEFAULT', instead of a user assigned specific value. This may cause I/O contention or incompatibility with the board power or connectivity affecting performance, signal integrity or in extreme cases cause damage to the device or the components to which it is connected. To correct this violation, specify all I/O standards. This design will fail to generate a bitstream unless all logical ports have a user specified I/O standard value defined. To allow bitstream creation with unspecified I/O standard values (not recommended), use this command: set_property SEVERITY {Warning} [get_drc_checks NSTD-1].  NOTE: When using the Vivado Runs infrastructure (e.g. launch_runs Tcl command), add this command to a .tcl file and add that file as a pre-hook for write_bitstream step for the implementation run. Problem ports: a_bL, a_bR, input, and output.

My top module is

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity lab16 is
Port ( sw : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       led : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
       btnL : in STD_LOGIC;
       btnR : in STD_LOGIC);
end lab16;

architecture Behavioral of lab16 is

signal A , B , C , D , W , X , Y , Z , bL, bR. c1 : STD_LOGIC;
component Lab16_1
        Port ( a_A, a_bL, a_bR, clock, reset: in STD_LOGIC;
               a_N : out STD_LOGIC);        
    end component;

begin

A <= sw(0);
B <= sw(1);
C <= sw(2);
D <= sw(3);

bR <= btnR;
bL <= btnL;
c1 <= clk;
FlipFlop1:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => A, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => W);
FlipFlop2:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => B, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => X);
FlipFlop3:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => C, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Y);
FlipFlop4:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => D, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Z);
led(0) <= sw(0);
led(1) <= sw(1);
led(2) <= sw(2);
led(3) <= sw(3);
led(4) <= W;
led(5) <= X;
led(6) <= Y;
led(7) <= Z;

end Behavioral;
```

Lower Module

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Lab16_1 is
    port(
         a_A, a_bL, a_bR, reset, clock : in STD_LOGIC;
         a_N : out STD_LOGIC
        );
end entity Lab16_1;

architecture Behavioral of Lab16_1 is
begin
process (a_bL, a_bR) is
begin
  --if rising_edge(clock) then  
     if (a_bL ='1') then   
        a_N <= '0';
     elsif (a_bR = '1') then
        a_N <= a_A;

     end if;
  --end if;
end process;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

Constraint File

```
 ## Switches
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {sw[0]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {sw[1]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {sw[2]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {sw[3]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[3]}]

## LEDs
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports {led[0]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports {led[1]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports {led[2]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V19 [get_ports {led[3]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W18 [get_ports {led[4]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U15 [get_ports {led[5]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U14 [get_ports {led[6]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V14 [get_ports {led[7]}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[7]}]

##Buttons
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W19 [get_ports btnL]                       
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnL]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T17 [get_ports btnR]                        
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports btnR]

set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets btnR]
```

Comment: What is your target platform (fpga)?

Comment: I assume you are asking what I am programming which is a Basys 3 board Xilinx Artix-7 FPGA (XC7A35T-ICPG236C). Ihave updated the code so the port map is correct and update in my question, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error only when the wrong module is set as “top”. See the edit to my answer - specifically the last paragraph.

Comment: I noticed that and set the right module to be the top but got the same error but with different problem ports, led(8) and led (9) I think. I started from scratch and just copy paste the code and it worked. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It would seem then, that the answer does address the error you posted - since you say the error details changed after you set the correct unit as the top module. Glad it’s working now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how you got it past the synthesis stage, let alone the implementation.

In your top module, you specify component `Lab16_1` with a port map that doesn't resemble the actual ports at all.

you write (in the top module):

```
component Lab16_1
    Port ( input, cl_k, rs_t: in STD_LOGIC;
           output : out STD_LOGIC);        
end component;
```

whereas your actual ports are declared as

```
entity Lab16_1 is
port(
  clk : in  std_logic;
  rst : in  std_logic;
  pre : in  std_logic;
  ce  : in  std_logic;
  d   : in  std_logic;
  q   : out std_logic
);
end entity Lab16_1;
```

Once you've fixed that, you still have the issue that your flip-flop is a latch. I assume you understand this, since you've commented out your usage of the `clk` signal, but I point it out anyway to make you aware that Vivado will issue heaps of warnings related to this.

---

*Update based on edited post*

Your updated code still needs some modification. But if I make the assumption that by:

```
FlipFlop1:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => A, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => W);
FlipFlop2:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => B, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => X);
FlipFlop3:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => C, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Y);
FlipFlop4:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => D, a_bL => bL, a_bR => bR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Z);
```

you really mean:

```
FlipFlop1:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => A, a_bL => btnL, a_bR => btnR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => W);
FlipFlop2:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => B, a_bL => btnL, a_bR => btnR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => X);
FlipFlop3:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => C, a_bL => btnL, a_bR => btnR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Y);
FlipFlop4:  Lab16_1 port map (a_A => D, a_bL => btnL, a_bR => btnR, reset => '0', clock => '1', a_N => Z);
```

then, I am able to generate a bitstream. I would suggest you double-check that your project is targeting the right FPGA, and that your constraints file is actually enabled (right-click on the file in the Hierarchy). If you have multiple constraints files, you should also make sure you have the correct one targeted.

One thing which will definitely cause this error message, is if your project does not have **lab16** set as your **top** module. Right-click on *lab16 - Behavioral* in the Sources⟶Hierarchy tab, and click *Set as Top*.